# Web API OAUTH - Distinguish between if Identify Token Expired or UnAuthorized

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Am currently developing an Authorization server using Owin, Oauth, Claims.

Below is my Oauth Configuration and i have 2 questions

```
 OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
  {

     AllowInsecureHttp = true,
     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
     AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000),
     Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
     //RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
  };
     app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
     app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

If the token is expired and user accessing using the expired token user is getting  **401(unAuthorized)**.Checking using Fiddler.

How can i send a customized message to an user stating your token as expired. Which function or module i need to override.

and my another quesiton is  What is the use of the below line ?

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()); 
Do i really need this to implement because when i checked it still works without the above line. Any security violation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly customize the behavior for expired tokens but you can do that with a custom middleware.

First override the `AuthenticationTokenProvider` so that you can intercept the authentication ticket before it is discarded as expired.

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);

        if (context.Ticket != null &&
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue &&
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.LocalDateTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            //store the expiration in the owin context so that we can read it later a middleware
            context.OwinContext.Set("custom.ExpriredToken", true);
        }
    }
}
```

and configure it in the Startup along with a small custom middleware

```cs
using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AccessTokenProvider = new CustomAuthenticationTokenProvider()
});

//after the request has been authenticated or not
//check for our custom env setting and act accordingly
app.Use(new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(next => (env) =>
{
    var ctx = new OwinContext(env);
    if (ctx.Get<bool>("custom.ExpriredToken"))
    {
        //do wathever you want with the response
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        ctx.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Token exprired";

        //terminate the request with this middleware
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    else
    {
        //proceed with the rest of the middleware pipeline
        return next(env);
    }
}));
```

If you have noticed I've placed the custom middleware after the call to `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` and this is important and stems from the answer to your second question.

The `OAuthBearerAuthenticationMidlleware` is responsible for the authentication but not for the authorization. So it just reads the token and fills in the information so that it can be accessed with `IAuthenticationManager` later in the pipeline.

So yes, with or without it all your request will come out as 401(unauthorized), even those with valid tokens.

Comment: Perfect Solution, Save Me A Lot Of Time!